# Matlab nlinfit is diverging

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, nonlinear-functions

I have a known model which I am trying to fit to real data.

```
fun = @(b,x) b(1)*x(:,1)./(x(:,2).^b(2));
beta0 = [70 1.1]; % expected range is 40-130, and 1.0-1.3
[beta,r]=nlinfit(X,tmp_y,fun,beta0);
```

When I use nlinfit, it tells me that my function is returning values of Inf. I stepped down into the code and discovered that on the second iteration of the fit, it is overcompensating the second beta term, dropping it to -80. With very large values for `x(:,2)`, this results in divide-by-zero for all values of `x`.

Are there options I can set to prevent this from happening? I've read the documentation, but I'm not understanding very well what all of the options actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Letś suppose that the only problem in your code is that the values are diverging because some zero or negative values arise. If this is the case, there is simple trick to solve this problem. Instead of estimating b(i) directly, define c(i)=ln(b(i)) which implies that b(i)=exp(c(i)). Therefore, replace b(i) by exp(c(i)) in your equation.

fun = @(c,x) exp(c(1))*x(:,1)./(x(:,2).^exp(c(2)));

After the estimation of c(i) evaluate b(i)=exp(c(i)). Note that in this case you allow c(i) have zero and negative values, but b(i) is always positive.

Comment: This does not work, because the problem isn't that `b(i)` is zero, it's that `x(:,2)^b(i)` is zero. However, your idea to manipulate the equation made me try inverting the entire equation, so that zero would be in the numerator, not the denominator. This allowed the solution to converge, so now it's a matter of determining if it is converging correctly.

Comment: @DavidK x(:,2)^b(i) can only be zero if X(:,2) is zero (x(:,2) is your data so it does not make sense) or b(i) is very negative - the solution above avoids this.  Sorry, I didnt understand your point.